# Extract Raster from Raster using Polygon shapefile in R

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, line

I am new to R and using the raster package. I have a problem extracting polygons from an existing raster file. If I use

```
extract(raster, poly_shape)
```

function on the raster it always creates a list with the data. What I really want is to extract another raster file that I can load with ArcGIS again.
After reading a bit more I think the crop function is what I really need. But when I try to use this function

```
crop(raster, poly_shape)
```

I get this Error:

```
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap
In addition: Warning message:
In intersect(extent(x), extent(y)) : Objects do not overlap
```

The files raster and poly_shape are the same for both functions. Can you tell me what could be wrong here? Is it even right that the crop function creates another raster and not a list?

**EDIT**: The extent() function does not work for me. I still get the same error. But I am sure the 2 datasets overlap! With the

```
extract(raster, poly_shape)
```

I get the right data from it. Just as a list and not as a raster like I want to have it. I just loaded the datasets in ArcGIS before and they fit very well so I did not check the projection. Now I tried

```
projection(raster) # "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"
projection(poly_shape) # "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"
```

and you can see that the projections do not fit. The extract function seems to be able to automatically transform the files in the right way. I know that because I did the following:

- I cut out the exact part of the polygon I extracted in R also in ArcGIS
- I calculated the sum of all values of the extracted R polygon (list)
- I calculated the sum of all raster cells that I cut out in ArcGIS

The 2 have the exact same result so I guess the conclusion should be that the extract function did work correct.
Now I have 2 options I guess:

1. I need a way to get a Raster out of the extracted list again or
2. The 2 datasets (raster + poly_shape) need to use the same prjection and the crop function should work

What would you suggest to do here?

Comment: What if it is a 4 bands rgbi raster?
Bands are lost so far...

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour]. Then consider editing your answer to provide additional information and references. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more info.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155235)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I actually searched for was the `mask()` function.

`mask(raster, poly_shape)`

works without errors and returns what I searched for.

Comment: Reproject your data so it is in the same projection space. Even in ArcGIS, where on the fly projection is automatic, it is very bad practice to conduct analysis in different projections. With data in different projections you data will not share common extents, which is the error you are receiving.

Comment: Use projectExtent() to get just the extent for cropping the raster.

Comment: To fit the Q&A format of the site this should be placed into the main body of the question as an edit/update (and then add a comment to the answer this is in "reply" to so they know there's more to look at).

Comment: @mattwilkie Sorry for not fitting the format but my text was too long to post it as a comment here. @JeffreyEvans I tried the following: `projection(raster) = projection(poly_shape)` and the other way around `projection(poly_shape) = projection(raster)` but both ways produce the same error: `Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap
In addition: Warning message:
In intersect(extent(x), extent(y)) : Objects do not overlap`. Is there a way how I can see which projection is used on the fly by using the extract() function (because that one obviously works)?

Comment: I solved this by exporting the 2 datasets from ArcMap again using the current dataframe as reference. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The crop function still is not what I searched for because it extracts the bbox and not just data inside the polygon. Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: What I actually searched for was the mask() function. `mask(raster, poly_shape)` works without errors and returns what I searched for.

Comment: @user3447301 The `mask` answer seems correct and needs to be more prominent.

Answer (score 22):

The extract function is behaving exactly as it should. You can force the crop function to use the extent of the polygon and then mask the object to return the exact raster representing the polygon area. If you continue to receive the error it means that your data, in fact, does not overlap.

Please keep in mind that R does not perform "on the fly" projection so, check your projections. You can check if your extents overlap using the "extent()" function.

Here is an example of cropping using the polygon extent then masking the resulting raster using the "rasterized" polygon.

```
# Add required packages
require(raster)
require(rgeos)
require(sp)

# Create some data using meuse 
data(meuse)
  coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
    proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
data(meuse.grid)
  coordinates(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
    proj4string(meuse.grid) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
      gridded(meuse.grid) = TRUE    
        r <- raster(meuse.grid) 
          r[] <- runif(ncell(r))

# Create a polygon
f <- gBuffer(meuse[10,], byid=FALSE, id=NULL, width=250, 
                         joinStyle="ROUND", quadsegs=10)   

# Plot full raster and polygon                       
plot(r)
  plot(f,add=T)

# Crop using extent, rasterize polygon and finally, create poly-raster
#          **** This is the code that you are after ****  
cr <- crop(r, extent(f), snap="out")                    
  fr <- rasterize(f, cr)   
    lr <- mask(x=cr, mask=fr)

# Plot results
plot(lr)
  plot(f,add=T)
```

Comment: extract() *does* perform on the fly reprojection, but crop() does not. That might account for some confusion

Comment: @Jefferey crop() and mask() only clip the raster according to the rectangular extents of the polygon it does not clip it from within the boundary of the polygon. Any idea what commands could clip the raster within the boundary of the given polygon?

Comment: @Chintan Sheth, for mask to subset within the polygon you need to have a raster representing the values within the polygon. This is why you rasterize the subset polygon and then mask to it. The crop step is to reduce the extent of the raster to the same as the subset polygon, which in the past, if skipped, would throw an extent mismatch error.

Comment: `spTransform` from the `sp` package (that is sometimes automatically loaded with other spatial R packages) allows to reprojection so that both files are in the same projection eg. `good_poly=spTransform(spolygon, CRSobj=crs(raster_file))`

Comment: @user3386170, Huh? Not sure what you are getting at. This question occurred at a time when the raster package just added "on the fly projection" within some if its functions. These functions had previously thrown an error when projections did not match, but this post was from 2014. You should also be aware of always loading rgdal when using sp::spTransform() as, it adds additional, important, functionality behind the scenes.

Comment: My turn for "Huh?". Are you saying that matching projections doesn't matter anymore with recent `raster` package updates? I just tried to crop a raster with a polygon that had different projections and I ran into this error: `Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap`.  When I transformed the polygon, the `crop` was performed.  I am "getting at" proposing a solution for someone who runs into rasters and polygons with different projections causing problems.

Comment: Only certain functions eg., extract(). It makes sense that something like crop and mask would not provide on-the-fly projection. I am notable weary of on-the-fly projections and would rather have the error. It keeps people honest.

Comment: Still not sure why you don't think it is relevant to guide users to how to resolve issues when polygon and raster are in different projections (if you say on-the-fly can be problematic, I trust your judgement on that). This post is still useful/relevant three years later, e.g. your example/instructions helped me perform this operation on my dataset.

Comment: The extent of the cropping features had to be within the extent of `x` for me. It errored with `Error in methods::validObject(y) : invalid class “Extent” object: TRUE` 
Seems like a bug. `help(crop)` reads: "Areas included in y but outside the extent of x are ignored." This doesn't suggest an error would be thrown.

Answer (score -1):

Extent works just fine ... I think your extent's Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, and Ymax are different from your raster's X and Y - i.e. they are set opposite