# Does the inputs extent have to be identical for raster::intersect to crop a RGB GEOTiff?

Tags: raster, r, intersection, extents, rgeos

**Background:** I have a shapefile with multiple polygons over a large area and then I also have GEOTiff image files. I want to crop the TIFF files with each of the polygons. The problem is that when I use raster::intersect to try and do it, I get the error:

```
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap
```

This is my (pseudo)code for loading the shapefile and selecting a polygon from that shapefile:

```
 Mineralrights.shape<-readOGR(dsn = "C:/Users/blablabla/Shapefiles",layer = "Mineral Rights")  
 Mineralrights.shape <- spTransform(Mineralrights.shape, "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs")  
 tempshape <- Mineralrights.shape[Mineralrights.shape$GID == "2097674",]
```

And this is my (pseudo)code for loading the GEOTiff as a raster:

```
  Aerialfiletocheck <- raster(paste0(getwd(),"/","2923AD_06_2014_783.tif"))  
  projection(Aerialfiletocheck) <- projection(tempshape)
```

I don't think the projections is the issue here, since all the source files (shapefile and TIFFS) uses a standard WGS84 ellipse, I just set the projections explicitly for safety. Then call:

```
  clip <- raster::intersect(Aerialfiletocheck,tempshape)
```

And this is when I get the error about the extents that do not overlap. To be sure, I tried to simplify the GEOTiff to just its extent and then plotting that over the specific polygon I have selected:

```
  raam <- projectExtent(Aerialfiletocheck,"+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs")
  raam.shape <- as(raam@extent, 'SpatialPolygons')
  plot(raam.shape)
  plot(tempshape,add=T)
```

Yielding this plot, where the large rectangle is the extent of the GEOTiff and the funny triangle being the polygon I selected. [image]

These are the parameters requested

```
 > Aerialfiletocheck@extent
    class       : Extent 
    xmin        : 24127.25 
    xmax        : 29297.25 
    ymin        : -3248250 
    ymax        : -3242397 
 > tempshape@bbox
            min       max
    x  23.25377  23.25875
    y -29.33836 -29.33380
```

**Problem:** To me it looks like their extents very much overlaps, hence my question: Does the inputs' extent have to be identical for raster::intersect to crop a RGB GEOTiff?
That would make no sense to me, because the whole idea of raster::intersect is to "crop" the one with the other, which would imply that their extents will overlap, but not necessarily be identical.

**What else have I tried:** 
1) I have replaced the raster with another polygon and then get the expected result.

2) I have tried `base::crop`which give the same error, which I expected because I think when one input is a raster, `intersect` just calls `crop`

3) I have tried `rgeos:gIntersection` which results in an error about the raster not having a proj4string slot, which makes no sense to me.

4) I have read these posts (and many others): [Extracting intersection areas in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140504/extracting-intersection-areas-in-r)

[Crop a raster file in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229356/crop-a-raster-file-in-r)

[Extract Raster from Raster using Polygon shapefile in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92221/extract-raster-from-raster-using-polygon-shapefile-in-r)

[GDAL: Convert specific RGB (GeoTIFF) color to transparent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25064/gdal-convert-specific-rgb-geotiff-color-to-transparent)

Comment: Please, add to the post `Aerialfiletocheck@extent` and `tempshape@bbox`

Comment: @aldo_tapia I see what you did there. It seems the projection of the tiff is in Easting/Westings or polar coordinates or something. Is `projection(Aerialfiletocheck) <- projection(tempshape)` somehow not working?

Comment: Yes, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `projectRaster(Aerialfiletocheck,tempshape)` to change raster's projection... **BUT!** do not change raster projection, change vector.

If you pretend to project raster, you have two methods to resample information (nearest neighbor and bilinear interpolation). As a resample, new information will be created, so you'll change the original data of your raster.

Instead of this, use `spTransform(tempshape, Aerialfiletocheck@crs)` to project vector. With the new vector object you can crop, mask, and so on.

Comment: you beauty! It works.

Comment: Can you explain why my initial plot showed that their extents do overlap even though they were in different coordinate systems?

Comment: @WaldovdM as function documentation says: `projectExtent` returns a RasterLayer with a projected extent, but without any values. The CRS used is the same one that shape layer, so the plot shows overlapping features.